# Proof that Polygonal Billiards Have Zero Entropy

Tags: dynamical-systems, entropy, ergodic-theory, polygons, billiards

I'm reading this paper "Billiards In Polygons" by Boldrighini et al. They say that polygonal billiards have zero [measure-theoretic entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure-preserving_dynamical_system#Measure-theoretic_entropy), because a given element of the configuration space is almost surely determined by its forward hit-sequence(the sequence of sides it collides with). Why does being so determined imply zero entropy?

Comment: In stastical mechanics, entropy is a measure of the probability distribution of microstates with regards to a specific macrostate; the greater the number of microstates leading to a macrostate, the greater the entropy and vice-versa. The macrostate here is the final position of the billiards and the microstates are the possible sequences of sides being collided with. A macrostate being almost surely determined by a particular sequence of sides means that there are almost no others leading to that macrostate, hence an entropy of (practically) zero for any given macrostate.

Comment: I'm asking about the topological entropy as defined e.g. here(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_entropy), not statistical mechanical entropy(which doesn't make sense here in any case)

Comment: The sentence quoted out of context is incomprehensible. In any case, vanishing of entropy of polygonal billiards is a known theorem. Do you want to see a reference?

Comment: No, I was asking about a step in the proof given in the paper by Boldrighini

Comment: *actually the measure-theoretic entropy, not topological(I edited the main post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the billiard flow is a special flow over the shift $\sigma$ determined by the hit sides, hence by Abramov the entropy of the flow is proportional to that of the shift. Next, this shift has zero entropy because the fact that you state is equivalent to the shift having a one-sided generator: if $\alpha$ is the partition determined by the cylinder sets at the zeroth coordinate, then the ambient sigma-algebra $\mathcal{B}$ is up to a measure zero set equal to the sub-sigma-algebra corresponding to the "past partition"

$$\alpha_1^\infty=\prod_{k\geq1}\sigma^{-k}(\alpha)$$

(the product signifies the coarsest common refiner, often denoted by $\bigvee$). Thus $\alpha$ is a (two-sided) generator too, whence the entropy of $\sigma$ is the entropy of $\alpha$ conditioned on $\alpha_1^\infty=_{æ}\mathcal{B}$, which is zero. See e.g. Petersen's *Ergodic Theory*, pp.244-245 for more details.

Comment: Great answer, thanks.